# R & dplyr: using mutate() to get yearly totals

Tags: r, dplyr

Data like so:

```
data <- read.table(text="year level items
2014 a     12
2014 b     16
2014 c     7")
```

Would like to run that through `mutate()` and I guess `group_by` so I have a year and a total, so a row that's just:

`year items
2014  35`

Feel like it should be 101 simple but I can't quite figure this one out.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
out <- data %>% group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(items= sum(items, na.rm=T))
```

Comment: is `summarize()` more appropriate than a pass through `mutate()`?

Comment: I don't use `mutate` much; but, I think `data %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(items = sum(items, na.rm=T))` would also work